# How to compare table records for an entire table in a SQL SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to compare an attribute values of row 1 with row 2, row 2 with row 3, row 3 with row 4 and so on for the entire table. The table data set is small after applying a condition in the WHERE clause.

The comparison part of it involves joins to other tables (which I can manage).

```
ID    PROJECT    VALUE
B1    PRJ001     100
B2    PRJ001     200
B3    PRJ001     200
B4    PRJ001     300
.....
.....
B9    PRJ001     600
```

In the example above, I need to compare B1 to B2, B2 to B3 ... B8 to B9 and count the number of times the VALUES don't match.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Lead function

```
Select t.*, 
 LEAD(value,1) over (order by id) as next_value
From your_table t;
```

Also just to be clear, I hope this is just an example. Because if you add more id like 'B10' , then `order by` would put `B10` between `B1` and `B2`.

Comment: Thanks Utsav. I'll give it a go and see how I can incorporate this in my code.

And yes, this is just an example, I will be looking at the Created Date to determine the order but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Cool. Feel free to accept the answer so the question could be closed.